# Spring HttpSecurity: Custom web security expressions

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure the security of a new spring web application to check requests done against some of my urls.
Since none of the built-in expressions were valid for my logic, I decided to write my own, but it is not working at all.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/instances/**").permitAll()

                //Custom expresion to check against
                .antMatchers("/(?!login|user-profiles)/**").access("@checkAccess.hasRoleSelected()")


                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter(jwtConfig.getUri(), authenticationManager(), tokenService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class CheckAccess {
    public boolean hasRoleSelected() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans), to get this done you need a bean with a method returning a boolean value. While I do have both, the method is never called and no error is thrown.

What am I missing?

Btw, I am running 5.2.2 version of spring security.

Comment: In your custom matcher you are specifying that it is `antMatchers`, however `"/(?!login|user-profiles)/**"` is not a valid ant pattern. It looks like a combination of ant and regex. You can use `regexMatchers` if you want to use regex. Otherwise you should change the provided string to a valid ant pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your antMatcher is invalid.

```
.antMatchers("/(?!login|user-profiles)/**").
```

Have a look at the allowed patterns in the [AntPathMatcher doc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

It is basically, "?", "*" and "**".

You might want to give the regexMatcher a try, instead.

Comment: Jesus, you are right! I spent the whole afternoon blaming at the wrong guy...